# data encryption and decryption in laravel

Tags: laravel, encryption

How to encrypt and decrypt data in laravel on the basis custom key.

I'm having a outlet table where number of outlet created and each outlet is having unique encryption key which is i'm creating when outlet created.
so now each outlet is having products and i want to encrypt all the data inside product table like product_name, price, sku etc. the thing is that i found the way to data encrypt and decrypt but i want to encrypt and decrypt data on the basis of outlet encryption_key which is present in outlet table. And when i try to decrypt data at that time outlet encryption_key needs to be check and then data decrypt.
This is what i want but i don't know how to achieve this.

Please help.

[image]

I'm using **dustapplication/laravel-database-model-encryption** package for encryption

I have created encryption table for testing of encryption and
below is Encryption table model where I'm trying to use encryption

```
use EncryptableAttribute;

protected $table = 'encryption';
protected $encryptable  =['name','mobile'];
```

I'm using encryption like this.

Comment: it is from package @Rwd

Comment: I mention package name in details @Rwd